# Installing Mavericks on USB pen to run on Windows PCs

Tags: macos, windows, usb, install, startup

How can I install Apple's Mavericks on a pen drive, that I can then plug into a windows machine and boot from it?

I did that some years ago with 10.6: I installed it on a 16Gb pen drive and then I could just go to a windows machine, restart it, set its boot drive to my pen and then run Mac OSX on it. I have forgotten all the details of how to do it, and I don't even know if I still have that pen around. Nevertheless, I would like to do it again, but this time with Mavericks. Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it against Apple's EULA.

Comment: would this help: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-to-install-os-x-mavericks/

Comment: @Buscar웃 No, that is a guide to install Mavericks on a pen drive that is to be plugged into a **Mac** computer. I meant a hackintoshed version of Mavericks that runs on a windows machine instead.

Comment: do you mean Create Mavericks Bootable USB in Windows 8.1